# If a variety has a $Q$ model, does its blowing up also have $Q$ model?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

To be precise, suppose $X$ is a smooth variety defined over the rational number field $Q$, fix a $Q$ model of it, and let $P$ be a $Q$ point of $X$ under this model. Then take $\pi:\widetilde{X}\to X$ to be the geometric blowing-up of $X$ at $P$. Can we find a $Q$ model of $\widetilde{X}$ such that under that model, the morphism $\pi$ is also defined over $Q$? If not, what is the best thing we can do?

Thanks

Comment: Yes - the construction of the blowup as relative proj of a certain sheaf of ideals on $X$ should give you this, because the sheaf of ideals is defined over $\Bbb Q$. See Hartshorne chapter 2 section 7 for details.

Comment: @KReiser, Ah yes, thanks to your answer, that makes things clear.